# Angular base64 image pipe, Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, angular

I have to convert Image urls to base64 encoded strings (because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419686/render-svg-to-canvas-with-images/47420230#47420230))

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


declare var base64;

@Pipe({
  name: 'tobase64'
})
export class Tobase64Pipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    var xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHTTP.open('GET', value, true);
    xmlHTTP.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xmlHTTP.onload = (e) => {
        console.log('e',e);
      var arr = new Uint8Array(e.currentTarget.response);
      var raw = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, arr);
      var b64 = base64.encode(raw);
       var dataURL = "data:image/png;base64," + b64;
      return dataURL;
    };
    xmlHTTP.send();

    return null;
  }

}
```

Html

```
<image x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" [attr.xlink:href]="'assets/hand.jpg' | tobase64"    mask="url(#hole)" />
```

Error:

```
ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string it looks that it might help - there is a for-loop that you might need to include. possible duplicate also of the question.

Comment: ouch, a pipe that does an Http call. I don't think It's a good idea. Pipes rerun every time some change is made to the scoped component. That's why you are getting this error. just check your requests, It's overflowing the http stack.

Comment: Not to mention the .apply() which will execute a function for each charCode, which for a base64 encoded image will be more than a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is completely okay to do HTTP requests from a pipe. In your case you will eventually do just one. Consider this: if you bind a `src` attribute of an `img` to a property that can change dynamically, you will eventually make a server call any time the property changes; it's not really a big deal whether that call is an XHR call or a simple request for an image. The only two things I do not quite understand about your pipe is following:

1. Why use XMLHTTPRequest rather than Angular's Http or HttpClient services?
2. Why does your pipe return `null`? It seems that even if you did not get any errors, you won't still get the result

This solution will require two pipes to be clear: one is a custom pipe for making  XHR calls and the other is the Angular's built-in pipe `async`. Here is our custom pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Pipe({name: 'toBase64'})
export class ImagePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  transform(url: string) {
  const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'image/*'}); /* tell that XHR is going to receive an image as response, so it can be then converted to blob */
  return this.http.get(url, new RequestOptions({headers: headers, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob})) // specify that response should be treated as blob data
  .map(response => response.blob()) // take the blob
  .switchMap(blob => {
  // return new observable which emits a base64 string when blob is converted to base64
      return Observable.create(observer => { 
        const  reader = new FileReader(); 
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob); // convert blob to base64
        reader.onloadend = function() {             
              observer.next(reader.result); // emit the base64 string result
        }
     });
   });
  }
}
```

And here goes your html:

```
<image x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" [attr.xlink:href]="('assets/hand.jpg' | toBase64) | async"    mask="url(#hole)" />
```

We use our pipe to get an observable of a base64 string, and `async` to insert the actual emitted string inside the `src` tag.

One thing you need to keep in mind is CORS: your image serving server should be configured in a way that it accepts XHR calls for images from the domain your Angular app is running on, also, you will have to provide absolute urls to the custom pipe, otherwise it will make requests to the Angular app's domain itself. But in your case I assume you serve images from your own app, so this should not really be a concern.